# Efficiently invert threediagonal symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I need to invert a threediagonal symmetric $1000\times10000$ matrix (or of similar dimensions). Specifically I need to solve the following equation:
$$Ax=b$$
with
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}v_1&-\frac{dt}{2}&0&\cdots\\-\frac{dt}{2}&v_2&-\frac{dt}{2}&0&\dots\\0&-\frac{dt}{2}&v_3&-\frac{dt}{2}&0&\dots\\\vdots&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}$$
To be even more precise:
$$A=\mathbf1-\frac{dt}{2}\cdot(D2+V)\qquad b=(\mathbf1 + \frac{dt}{2} * (D2 + V)) * \psi$$
with
$$D2=\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&0&\cdots\\1&-2&1&0&\cdots\\0&1&\ddots&\ddots&0&\cdots\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}\qquad V=\begin{pmatrix}V_1&0&\cdots\\0&V_2&0&\cdots\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}$$
If you're curious, I need this for solving the one dimensional Schrödinger equation via the Crank-Nicolson iteration.

Does an efficient algorithm exist for solving such a system (or for inverting the matrix)? So far the best I found is the Gaussian elimination, which works in $\mathcal O(n^3)$ - but this would yield a billion iteration steps.

Comment: Use a sparse matrix solver. A problem adapted LU or QR decomposition should take time $O(n)$, back-substitution similarly $O(n)$ both times.

Comment: Thomas algorithm, which is a particular case of Gaussian elimination applied to a tridiagonal system, would be my choice

Comment: @VoB Thomas algorithm sounds perfect for that situation, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just too long for a comment.

You don't need (and don't have to) invert a matrix: just solve the linear system. That said, for tridiagonal matrices you can use [Thomas Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm), which is just Gaussian Elimination applied to a tridiagonal system. It's composed by two parts: the forward sweep and the backward one and it's easy to implement. You can find all the relevant information in the Wikipedia page

Comment: I realized that my matrix has complex elements (to be precise, $D2$ is scaled by a complex factor). Will the algorithm still work? I didn't find any information for that on Wikipedia or similar...

Comment: Try with a simple tridiagonal matrix to convince yourself. In any case, Gaussian elimination has no problems with complex entries, so also Thomas algorithm should have no problem. @MetaColon